# Send an E-mail to an internationalized E-mail address with Python / SMTPlib

Tags: python, smtp

In my Python application, I would like to be able to send mail to addresses like `っていった@example.jp`, `démo@example.fr`, or even `عرض@وزارة-الأتصالات.مصر`, which are perfectly valid.

When passing the address as UTF-8, I get an UnicodeDecodeException. If I encode the address with `address.encode('utf-8')`, no Python error but I get bounce mail explaining `Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 501 Malformed RCPT TO: - psmtp`.

What's the way to make everything work ?

Thanks.

Comment: as far as i know, non-ascii-chars in the localpart (before '@') are not allowed. The domain-part (after '@') must be IDN-encoded if non-ascii. Dunno about python.

Comment: non-ascii chars in the localpart are allowed, and valid. Well, pretty much anything is valid before the @, in fact.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9527510/633961

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the server you're talking to includes `UTF8SMTP` in its `EHLO` response. Otherwise it doesn't support [rfc5336](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5336). You can tell by using telnet or netcat to connect to the server and pretending to be an SMTP client.

Comment: Yep, thanks. Seems like the packaged version of Postfix in Ubuntu doesn't support that feature...