# unicode error in python

Tags: python

In the below code i get an error at `mailServer.sendmail(gmailUser, m.to_addr, msg.as_string())`

```
 2011-08-12 17:33:02,542 ERROR  send exception


  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "sendmail.py", line 33, in bulksend
      mailServer.sendmail(gmailUser, m.to_addr, msg.as_string()).replace(u'\xa0', '')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/email/Message.py", line 129, in as_string
      g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/email/Generator.py", line 82, in flatten
      self._write(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/email/Generator.py", line 113, in _write
      self._dispatch(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/email/Generator.py", line 139, in _dispatch
      meth(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/email/Generator.py", line 205, in _handle_multipart
      g.flatten(part, unixfrom=False)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/email/Generator.py", line 82, in flatten
      self._write(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/email/Generator.py", line 113, in _write
      self._dispatch(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/email/Generator.py", line 139, in _dispatch
      meth(msg)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.4/email/Generator.py", line 182, in _handle_text
      self._fp.write(payload)
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 173: ordinal not in range(128)
  o
```

This is the `send` method:

```
def send(request)
    qs = "......."
    if qs.count():
        smaid = qs[0].id
        gmailUser = 'no-reply@xx.com'
        gmailPassword = 'xx'
        mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        mailServer.ehlo()
        mailServer.starttls()
        mailServer.ehlo()
        mailServer.login(gmailUser, gmailPassword)
        tosend = MailQueue.objects.filter(school = smaid, send = 0)
        for m in tosend:
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = gmailUser
            msg['To'] = m.to_addr
            msg["Content-type"] = "text/html"
            sub = m.subject
            sub = sub.replace(u"\u2019"," ")
            msg['Subject'] = sub
            body = m.body
            body = body.replace(u"\u2019"," ")
            msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))
            mailServer.sendmail(gmailUser, m.to_addr, msg.as_string())
            m.send = 1
            m.save()
        mailServer.close()
    except:
    write_exception("send exception")
```

Comment: This code is not syntactically valid (no colon after `def send(request)`, wrong indentation for `except`). Are you sure it's the code being executed?

Comment: Looks like your `msg` is not ascii-encoded. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870214/python-special-characters-giving-me-problems-from-pdfminer/6873578#6873578.

Comment: @Maxim: No, it's not ascii-encoded, but mainly because it is not encoded at all. Remember, unless it gets encoded as `base64`, it will always contain bytes above 0x7f (provided it contains such unicode codepoints, but it obviously does).

Comment: @Jan Hudec:So what is the solution......

Comment: @Jan Hudec Huh? I just changed formatting, at least I hope so. stackoverflow's diff shows exactly that, so how did I mess up?

Comment: @phihag: Sorry. The history view is totally confused. It says 'deleted X characters' beside your name, but the change deleting them is the one above that line while your change is the one below.

Comment: @Rajeev: I believe you have to encode the body before you give it to MIMEText. Like msg.attach(MIMEText(body.encode('utf-8'), 'text/html;charset=utf-8')) (hm, I don't know whether the second argument is mime-type (which should be as I wrote) or just name (in which case just 'html' was fine)).

Comment: @Jan Hudec:Belive it or not at first i tried the replace statement which didnt work!!!! But after i tried the same statement with a try catch block and it worked:(

Comment: @Rajeev: Since you have deleted (again, after I already reverted it once) the body of the method and the full traceback), the question is now UNANSWERABLE.

Answer (score 5):

First, you've got a bug that hasn't been triggered in the line before the sendmail call.
MIMEText defaults to trying to use the ASCII charset.  This obviously won't work for unicode.  You'd think it would default to using utf-8 if passed non-ASCII unicode, but it doesn't.  (I consider this a bug, but it is too late to fix it in Python2).  So your code should tell MIMEText which charset to use:

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html', 'utf-8'))
```

But your error is coming after the MIMEText step, which indicates it is probably unicode in your headers.  As mentioned, you can't send unicode to SMTP.  But the answer is *not* to encode it to utf-8.  You can't send utf-8 over SMTP in headers either (only in bodies).

To properly content-transfer-encode unicode in headers, use the Header class (email.header.Header):

```
msg['Subject'] = Header(sub, header_name='Subject')
```

Yes, this is a pain.  It is also a bit ugly since it CTE encodes the entire header, instead of just the parts that are non-ASCII. We're working on making this work easier and better in Python3, but we aren't quite there yet.

Addresses with unicode in them are more complicated.  You have to use Header to encode the display name, then pass that to formataddr:

```
disp_name = u'some unicode string'
addr = 'some@address.example.com'
msg['To'] = formataddr((str(Header(disp_name)), addr))
```

This address trick is not documented.  Many Python emall programs call Header on the entire address header, but this produces RFC invalid results (fortunately a lot of mailers handle the decoding correctly anyway).

All of this should be much better in Python 3.3.

Answer (score 2):

SMTP does not understand unicode. You have to encode the headers, and message body to byte strings before passing them to SMTPLIB.

I would recommend you to use marrow.mailer instead of rolling your own. marrow.mailer already encodes everything for you, even Internationalized Domain Names.

https://github.com/marrow/marrow.mailer

Comment: Now can you tell where exactly the encoding has to happen in the snippet in question? I'd guess either `MIMEText` needs to get extra argument for encoding or it's result needs to be encoded.

Comment: As I said, the header (Subject), and the message body.

Comment: As the author of marrow.mailer (formerly TurboMail) I can highly recommend it.  I may be biased, though.  ;)

It also offers a direct SMTP client (though sendmail is supported too) which is far more efficient than sendmail execution, allowing you to send up to a few hundred messages per second when properly configured, as well as AppEngine and Amazon SES support.  It also offers background delivery, rich text, and easy attachment support.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like when you do `msg.as_string()`, the library is eventually writing it to a file-like object, which is where the error is thrown. It's likely that the object is expecting an ASCII encoding, so Unicode is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `msg.as_string()` that fails. It fails because the body is `unicode` (instead of `str`) *and* contains some codepoints above 128.

To fix this, make sure the body in `msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))` is of type `str`, probably by encoding it.

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(body.encode('utf-8'), 'html'))
```

You will have to set the encoding too. It think it would be:

```
msg["Content-type"] = "text/html;charset=utf-8"
```